# Some Double Nvr Problems in same Network

Tags: networking, switch, video-streaming

We have a network camera system with 60 ip cameras.  I realized today that some of the cameras are freezing. Approximately 30% cameras are freezing. I check cameras itself and network cables; all working normally. And then i checked the system structure.
The system consists 2 nvrs and 60 ip cameras with same brand. And 3  Poe switches(24 port x 3).
All cameras are  in the same network 192.168.1.50-192.168.1.110
Nvr's are also in the same network with ip addresses former is 192.168.140 and latter is 141.
First Nvr works with first 23 cameras(all cameras are in the third switch with and cameras ip range 50-73), and second nvr works with remaining 37 cameras(23 of the cameras are in the 2nd switch, the others are in the 1st switch, cameras ip range 74-110).

When i check swiches, i saw 2 nvrs connected to the same (first) switch, and than first switch linked with second and third switch.

Is this structure normal? I am thinking to divide this combined structure and than make two independent camera system. Will this change help me to get over the freezing issue?

Edit:All 60 cameras record in full HD 25fps.

Comment: If it were me, I'd be looking at switch statistics, like port utilization, CPU and memory utilization, pause frames, send and receive errors, broadcast packets, etc. before I redesigned the network.

Comment: So, I need to learn the necessary commands that I can connect to the switch console and see the statistics. Thank you